# Login Form - Unable to Login using php

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I'm trying to code a login script using the following:

**A Jquery snippet**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('div#login-button').click(function(){
            var email = $("#login_email").val();
            var password = $("#login_password").val();
            $.post("functions/login.php?email="+email+"&password="+password, {
            }, function(response){
                if($(response).html() == "correct")
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                else window.alert($(response).html());
            });
});

});
</script>
```

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="login-type-1">
            E-mail:<input type="text" id="login_email" name="email" value="Type your Email ID" class="input" maxlength="100"/><br />
            Password:<input type="password" id="login_password" name="password" value="password" class="input" maxlength="30"/>
        <a href="#"><div id="login-button"><span>Log in</span></div></a>
</div>
```

**functions/login.php**:

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');

        session_start();

        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        if(!$email || $email == "Type your Email ID")
            echo "<p>Please input your email id.</p>";
        if(!$password)
            echo "<p>Please input your password.</p>";

        if($email && $password && $email != "Type your Email ID"){
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT u_id, u_fname, u_lname, u_email FROM user_data WHERE u_password = '".md5($password)."' AND u_email = '".$email."'");
            $result = mysql_num_rows($check);
            if ($result == 1){

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);

                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['u_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_fname'] = $row['u_fname'];
                $_SESSION['u_lname'] = $row['u_lname'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['u_email'];
                $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row['u_fname']." ".$row['u_lname'];

                echo "<p>correct</p>";

            }
            else {
                echo "<p>Invalid Authentication</p>";
            }
        }
?>
```

**Database connection:**

```
class db {
    public static $hostname_adminconn = "localhost";
    public static $database_adminconn = "masterdb";
    public static $username_adminconn = "root";
    public static $password_adminconn = "qwerty";
    public static $adminconn;

    public static function dbDb() {
        return db::$database_adminconn;
    }
    public static function dbConn() {
        return db::$adminconn;
    }
}
db::$adminconn = mysql_connect(db::$hostname_adminconn, db::$username_adminconn, db::$password_adminconn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Still, I'm unable to login. Could someone help me in debugging it?

Comment: This is not a free debugging service, you should come up with a specific error with a relevant code..

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your PHP returns this:

```
echo "<p>correct</p>";
```

But JavaScript checks for this:

```
if($(response).html() == "correct")
```

That comparison will not work.

Having said that, you should return a more suitable response type, such as [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    'res' => 'ok',
));
```

In your JavaScript:

```
if (response.res === 'ok') {
```

Comment: @Jack: I? don't have any prior knowledge of JSON. I tried removing `<p>` from the `php` code of my `login script`. Still I'm unable to login. Is there a way of doing it without JSON?

Comment: @xan Well, have you done any debugging? What does the server return exactly? If the server always returns failure, it's PHP. Otherwise, it's something in JavaScript.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, I did what you just instructed. But I'm not being navigated to my `logged_in` page. However, if I manually enter the `logged_in` page, I'm able to see all the variables from SQL tables of that particular user.